# is_paged() not working inside a function used to filter. WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I use is_paged() inside a function to add a filter in the functions.php. I want to remove an action on all paginated result pages. is_paged() is supposed to return exactly that but when used inside functions.php it doesn't

```
function rankmath_disable_features() {
    // This works
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        remove_all_actions( 'rank_math/head' );
    }
    // This doesn't
    if (is_paged()) {
        remove_all_actions( 'rank_math/head' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by hooking your rankmath_disable_features function into template_redirect action:

```
function rankmath_disable_features() {
    // This works
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
        remove_all_actions( 'rank_math/head' );
    }
    // This should work now
    if (is_paged()) {
        remove_all_actions( 'rank_math/head' );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rankmath_disable_features' );
```